# Are proxymail.facebook.com email address still supported?

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-authentication

They all seem to be either bouncing explicitly or silently not going through now (0 open/click rate), and they had been working since they first introduced the feature.  I know they aren't giving users the option to choose a proxymail.facebook.com address anymore in the newer Auth box.  Thanks.

Comment: Almost exactly a year later. I am still trying to figure this out. did you get anywhere with your research? Isn't crazy that there is no official documentation on this? I have 7000 users emails with app+blahlbahblah and I dont know what to do with them or if they still work etc. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the specific question I asked so long ago.  I think Facebook must have had a bug for a while that broke the *@proxymail.facebook.com email integration, and it was during this period that I asked my original question.  However, looking at our email logs, I can see that we have had people click on links in email sent to these Facebook proxy emails at the end of October, so whatever the issue was must have been resolved, and I believe if you have a Facebook proxy email, you can safely send to it.

That being said, of course the individual user may have revoked the email permission (in which case their proxy email will go to nowhere), and my impression is the same as sfussenegger that Facebook is no longer allowing users to use proxy email addresses.  I haven't seen the option to anonymize my email in a FB permissions dialog in a long time...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **NO**. Facebook no longer issues proxymail addresses.

Although there is no official reference which I can attach with this answer. But found this for **[reference](http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-25-support/5956-proxymailfacebookcom)**.

> Pretty sure it's still available to users, but Facebook rolls out
>   updates to their dialog boxes slowly, so it's possible a newer (or
>   even an older) one doesn't have that option.

This was one link where you had that:-

[image]

[image]

Now after the recent updates the **Change** button was removed.

Comment: this does not exactly answer the question. The question is if previously generated addresses still work. I assume not, but since this is the first result Google came up with, I thought I'd try to attract someone who knows. The link you provided is from the time when Facebook introduced them, thus not very helpful.

Comment: @sfussenegger:- Yes I agree. But I searched as much as possible and the best I came up was this. There were many places where I found that  **Facebook no longer issues proxymail addresses.** And neither there is any support for the addresses which were issued.

Comment: @sfussenegger:- Also since there were many updates since the question was asked and also many updates on facebook as well so the best I would guess is that they would have migrated all the addresses!! :)

Comment: Sorry, the link you posted is from February 2013. Interesting that they still issued them 8 month ago, quite some time after this question.

Comment: @sfussenegger:- Dont take me wrong and neither I am doing this for bounty reward but the same link said that after the update those changes were gone. Earlier they use to have that **Change** button which they mentioned but now its removed and also the proxy address support! P.S. I didnt found any official document otherwise I could have convinced you! :)

Comment: @sfussenegger:- For your information just one more link which may actually help you what I wanted to convey:- http://atechwritersays.wordpress.com/tag/xxxxproxymail-facebook-com/

Comment: still, it doesn't answer what happens to mails sent to previously issued proxymail addresses.

Comment: @sfussenegger:- Thats what I am trying to say that it migrated them. Just trying to find any doc which can convince you! ;)

Comment: @sfussenegger:- The most probable guess I could make is that they would have been converted to actual emails as proxy email were used to be handled for Facebook applications as a proxy so users do not have to release their email address publicly. Facebook assigns one when granting access to an application and the user requests an anonymous email instead. A temporary one is randomly generated for the user to receive emails from the application developer.

Comment: @sfussenegger:- And now they have provided a feature to hide the email address so that resolves there purpose!

Comment: unfortunately the question is still not completely answered, but thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Unfortunately, the most popular answer in this thread is not an answer to the question being asked. Yes we do know that facebook no longer allows users to mask their email with a proxy. However, the question is asking if developers can still send emails to the proxy email addresses collected in the past. This is still unanswered.
The original author of the question has since said he suspects that yes emails are being received because he's seeing user activity. However, it is not clear if this activity he is seeing is coming from emails that were sent a very long time ago where users are just s

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your question?

[Communicating Directly with Your Users via Email](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/355/)

Comment: this link doesn't work, so I have to go with "no" :)

Answer (score -3):

The reason you're getting no click-rates, is because in all outgoing emails that go through the facebook proxymail servers, the remailer is rewriting the links. So stuff of the form:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/">
```

gets re-written as:

```
<a href="l.php/?u=http://www.domain.com/">
```

Which is a broken link, and so your open-detection or click-detection probably won't work at all. And undoubtedly, users are confused (as evidenced by my users who ran into this).